# Scala: reflection against named arguments

Tags: scala, reflection, arguments

I'm trying to pass named arguments to a function from a regular Scala object like string/list/map, where the name of the argument and it's value are both variable (in my case from parsed user input). Is there a way to do this in Scala? I'm in principal looking for a short program in scala, similar to this in python:

```
def surprise(animal, color):
    print('Oh, a ' + color + ' ' + animal + '!')

arguments = {'animal': 'cat', 'color': 'black'}
surprise(**arguments)
```

Since python can unpack dictionaries into named arguments, this results in

```
Oh, a black cat!
```

I've been searching for this functionality in scala, but I could not find it. Can anyone give me an example on how to accomplish this in scala?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it is not that easy as in python, but I will try to propose couple of solutions. You need to extract your parameters from json (or other user input) with types and with order. It could be done using, for example, helper case class and play-json:

```
def surprise(animal: String, color: String): Unit = {
  println(s"Oh, a $color $animal!")
}

import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

case class FuncArguments(animal: String, color: String)
implicit val funcArgumentsFormat = Json.format[FuncArguments]

implicit def jsValueToFuncArguments(json: JsValue): FuncArguments =
  json.as[FuncArguments]

def surprise2(json: JsValue): Unit = {
  (surprise _).tupled(FuncArguments.unapply(json).get)
}
```

case class has same signature as your method. `implicit val funcArgumentsFormat`is play-json format to extract your data into case class (unsafe, because of `as`. Will throw Exception in case of missing required argument names/types in json), implicit def jsValueToFuncArguments converts your json into case class (theoretically also unsafe, because of `Option.get`, but do not think that you can get exception here). And helper function surprise2 to convert json into arguments.

Another approach would be, for example, to use some reflection:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

class SomeClass {
  def surprise(animal: String, color: String): Unit = {
    println(s"Oh, a $color $animal!")
  }
}

def surprise3(json: JsValue): Unit = {
  val method = classOf[SomeClass].getMethods.find(_.getName == "surprise").get
  val params = method.getParameters
  val values = params.map(_.getName).map(name => (json \ name).as[String])
  val ref = new SomeClass
  method.invoke(ref, values: _*)
}
```

In this example we have an assumption that all fields have the same type `String`, your function is inside class. Play-json is used for parsing. You get method, than argument names, than extract values for arguments (in same order as arguments) and than just apply them to function.

And calls:

```
val json = Json.obj("animal" -> "cat", "color" -> "black")

surprise2(json)
surprise3(json)
```

Comment: Hi Evgeny,
thanks a lot for your answer!!! I encounter two problems with your solution (probably I'm not knowledgeable enough to interpret them). The first solution doesn't compile for me:

`[error] No apply function found for mllab.Mllab.FuncArguments
[error]   implicit val funcArgumentsFormat = Json.format[FuncArguments]
[error] No Json deserializer found for type FuncArguments. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
[error]     json.as[FuncArguments]`

What did I get wrong?

Comment: And the second one gives an error at runtime: `JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List('arg0' is undefined on object: {"animal":"cat","color":"black"}),WrappedArray())))))`.

Comment: For first example you need first code snippet in scope. This one: `implicit val funcArgumentsFormat = Json.format[FuncArguments]`. For second - did you try my example or wrote yours?

Comment: Think that second issue could be related to different jvm or env. Try to output method arguments names, looks like they will be `arg0`, `arg1` etc for you.... In this case second solution could be platform dependant..

Comment: Figured out the first one, my bad! I had to add not onle `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"` but also `"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"` to my dependencies. Example 1 works like a charm now, thanks! I'm still figuring out numer 2.